# Two classes simple pass variable

Tags: java, android, gps

i have two simple classes. Main and some kind of gps helper. I'm trying to reach distance when gps posiotion has change (on Location change). It works and Toast good but when i try to save variable dis using setter, and reach it in my MainActivity(last method called ObliczanieOdl) a allways have 0.0. Why? Any suggestions?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
@BindView(R.id.butStop)
Button butStop;
@BindView(R.id.butWynik)
Button butKoniec;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private String dlugosc;
private String szerokosc;
private LatLng StartP, StopP;
private Date czasS;
private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private String adres;
private int Dystans;
private boolean oneStop = false;
private GPStracker gpStracker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    gpStracker = new GPStracker(getApplicationContext());

    dlugosc = intent.getStringExtra("dlugosc");
    szerokosc = intent.getStringExtra("szerokosc");
    StartP = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(szerokosc), Double.parseDouble(dlugosc));
    czasS = new Date();
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    mDatabaseHelper.setStartP(getAdres(StartP));//wyciągnięcie adresu rozpoczęcia podróży
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    addMarker(StartP);
}

private void addMarker(LatLng pozycja) {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pozycja));
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(pozycja)
            .zoom(10).build();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}

@OnClick(R.id.butStop)
public void butStop() {
    if (oneStop == false) {

        oneStop = true;
        Location location = gpStracker.getlocation();
        if (location != null) {
            StopP = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        }
        addMarker(StopP);

        mDatabaseHelper.setKoniecP(getAdres(StopP)); //wyciągnięcie adresu zakonczenia podróży
        //wyciągnięcie odległości i czasu podróży
        mDatabaseHelper.setCzasP(String.valueOf(ObliczanieOdl(StartP, StopP)) + " KM " + "w czasie: " + WyliczCzas());

        boolean insertData = mDatabaseHelper.addData();
    } else {
        toastMessage("Twoja podróż została zakończona");
    }
}

@OnClick(R.id.butWynik)
public void butKoniec() {
    if (oneStop == false) {
        toastMessage("Musisz zakończyć podróż wciskając STOP");
    } else {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, ListDataActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}


public double ObliczanieOdl() {

    Double metry = gpStracker.getDis();

    return metry;
}
```

}

and second as a GPS Helper:

```
public class GPStracker implements LocationListener {
Context context;
double plat;
double plon;
double clat;
double clon;

public double dis;

public GPStracker(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

public Location getlocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Uprawnienia nie przyznane", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean isGPSenabled;
    isGPSenabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (isGPSenabled) {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 1, this);
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        return location;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Proszę włączyć GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    clat = location.getLatitude();
    clon = location.getLongitude();
    if (clat != plat || clon != plon) {
        dis += getDistance(plat, plon, clat, clon);
        plat = clat;
        plon = clon;

        setDis(dis);
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(dis), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

public double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double latA = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    double lonA = Math.toRadians(lon1);
    double latB = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    double lonB = Math.toRadians(lon2);
    double cosAng = (Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonB - lonA)) +
            (Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB));
    double ang = Math.acos(cosAng);
    double dist = ang * 6371;
    return dist;
}

public double getDis() {
    return dis;
}

public void setDis(double dis) {
    this.dis = dis;
}
```

}

Comment: You add stuff to "dis" variable in onLocationChange, but I don't see where do you initialize it. Maybe that's the problem? Btw, naming everything in one language is a good habit (hi polish fellow!) :) In some cases you assign value to a field, but in some cases you use setter inside the same class. Better choose one style. And you don't need setter to a public field.

Comment: Hi Kamila - I don't think so that initializing is a problem because when i Toast dis it show me value wich i want....